# Solspace Super Search datepicker value

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I'm using Solspace Super Search, but wondering if it's possible to change the format for date-searching strings?

It's my understanding that you need to supply date ranges as the following `<input name="event_start_date-from" value="20141113">`, and filtering this way works just fine.

However, as I'm using a datepicker for the user, this isn't a very friendly way to display dates. Instead, it'd be preferable to show as something like the below.

[image]

Is this even possible, or maybe I've been going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Super Search accepts the YYYYMMDD format, but depending on your datepicker plugin, you might be able to set up the plugin to have a hidden field for the Super Search YYYYMMDD format, and a "dummy" field, visible to users, that would be formatted the way you want.

Comment: Yep, thats exactly what I've done - just wanted to see if there was a simpler, more obvious way that I was just missing. Thanks!